# Load return of PHP function into an HTML textbox

Tags: php, class, function

### PHP Class

```
<?php

class food {
    public function __construct ($parameter){
        $path = array("something") ;
        $this->getPath($path);
    }
    protected function getPath ($array){
        $json = json_encode($array);
    }
}

$print = new food(x);
```

### HTML

```
<!-- ... -->
<form name="form1" action="" method="GET" >
 <input type="text" id="hiddenbox" value="<?php $json ?>" />
</form>
<!-- ... -->
```

I want to load the `$json` value into the textbox. However, the value is not displayed. How do I get the return of `$this->getPath()` into the textbox?

Comment: I'm not re-editing to make this readable again :P  Hint: the `{}` button in the editor will format code for you so that it shows correctly.

Comment: hmmm.. which {} button ? is it an html button tag

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899299/phpoop-how-to-call-class-constructor-manually

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your class name is `$print`, and not `$json`. Secondly to run a function in a class you have to write `$print->getPath($array)` (and thus also define that $array somewhere). And third, you don't echo anything in `getPath()` function, so you can't just write `$json` or the function call there, you need to either have getPath 'echo' it or return `$json` variable.

In short? This question is horribly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are wanting to create a field `$json` in your `food` class. Here is how your `getPath` function should look:

```
protected function getPath ($array){
    $this->json = json_encode($array);
}
```

You will then want to replace your `value ="<?php $json ?>"` with the following (using the `$print` object you instantiated): `value ="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($print->json); ?>"`. The [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) bit is especially important as it "converts special characters to HTML entities".