# in magento use the method from parent class not the overriden class

Tags: php, magento

is it possible in magento php to invoke the method from parent class rather than from the overridden one,

I have extension overrides (A_CustomOptions_Model_Catalog_Product_Option extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option) and it overrides the construct method and I have got another extension wants to use the construct of parent class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option

is there a way to do this???

more explanation:

```
class A_CustomOptions_Model_Catalog_Product_Option extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option {

  protected function _construct() {
      parent::_construct();
      $this->_init('customoptions/product_option');       
  }
}
```

in another extension i'm getting collection for options

```
public function getOptions($srcId) {

   $options = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')
     ->getCollection()
     ->addTitleToResult(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
     ->addPriceToResult(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
     ->addProductToFilter($srcId)
     ->addValuesToResult();

   return $options;
}
```

however because this parent class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option is overridden, it doesn't return me the parent options not overridden ones
Thanks

Comment: Can you put some of your code in? I'm pretty sure you are asking for `parent::__construct();` but the wording is a little unclear so I might be missing something.

Comment: i edited the post with some code

Answer (score 0):

yes you can call parent constructor with use of below code

```
class A_CustomOptions_Model_Catalog_Product_Option extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option
{
   public function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

As your updated answer i think override class loaded at the last that might be not work.

hope this will sure work for you in simple OOP concept,

Comment: I can't remove the rest statements after parent::__construct(); in overridden class the method should be protected function _construct() {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('customoptions/product_option');       
    }

Comment: @user2797687,see oop rule http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899299/phpoop-how-to-call-class-constructor-manually

Comment: @user2797687,i am sure my answer is sure help you and it would be glad for me if you will acept my answer