# Pass an object in $_SESSION between 2 php scripts

Tags: php, session, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Storing 'objects' inside the $_SESSION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132194/php-storing-objects-inside-the-session)

I have 2 scripts files named 'search.php' and 'share.php' and I want to send information from the first to the second one. I created a var named $_SESSION['search'] wich is a object of the class Search, but I can't read the object in the second script file.

### search.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['search'] = new Search($text);

(...)
```

### share.php

```
session_start();
$itemList = $_SESSION['search']->getItemList(); // Error
```

Why? How can I pass info from one script to another in PHP?

Comment: What does the error say??? ALWAYS bring the error in your question, please. PS. Perhaps share.php haven't included the Search class so you can use their methods. (include more code)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to pass the variable using sessions then you need to add the variable to the session in search.php like so:

```
$itemlist = new Search($text);
$_SESSION['search']         = $itemlist;
```

And then get the variable back out in share.php like so:

```
$itemlist = $_SESSION['search'];
echo $itemlist;
```

If you are having problems I would check "new Search($text);" on the first page and be sure that it is what you actually want stored to begin with.

Comment: Thats what I'm doing in '$_SESSION['search'] = new Search($text);'

Comment: So what problem are you running into? If you echo $itemlist on share.php what do you get?

Comment: I get an error in php_error.log -> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getItemList() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SAPP2/share.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP automagically serializes objects in a session.

You CANNOT have any members in that object that are resources (ie a db connection etc.). If you need them in there you need to add __sleep and __wake methods to the object you wish to store in the session. __sleep renders the obj as a value obj (an array actually as you must return an array) and the __wake method should reconstruct the obj based on that array.

read [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.sleep)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are only missing an include of your php file containing the `Search` class.

```
require_once('Search.php');
```

If the class is not known at the moment you deserialize the object from the session, then PHP makes a "dummy" object, only containing the attributes, but without knowledge about it's methods. If you include the class, then PHP can deserialize it to a real object of this class.