# bitwise permissions not working PHP

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

im trying to learn to use bitwise permissions for in my application.
Problem is, it's not working :(

When a user logs in, i save a user object in the session, which looks like this :

```
    [user] => User Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [firstname] => Firstname
        [lastname] => Lastname
        [emailaddress] => email@adres
        [permissions] => 16
    )
```

i have a class called authenticate, in which i define some contants, which are these :

```
class authenticate {   

const GUEST = 1;  // 1
const USER = 10;  // 2
const MODERATOR = 1000; // 8
const ADMIN = 10000; // 16
```

Now when a user logs in in the admin, i want to make sure the user has admin rights, which i try to check this way :

```
  if ($_SESSION['user']->permissions & authenticate::ADMIN){
             echo 'yep admin';
  }else {
             echo 'no admin';
  }
```

When i have a user that does lets say have a number 8 as permission, its not an admin and it should say no admin.. but it doesn't it always says yep admin ..

could anyone tell me what i am doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Those... aren't bitwise. Those are decimal-wise. (Ten-wise?) Furthermore I don't think you aren't checking for bitwise permissions right — it should be `perm & required_perm === required_perm`. (Though maybe not.) PHP 5.4+ supports binary literal notation in the form `0b0101`.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132194/php-storing-objects-inside-the-session it's usually not a good idea to store objects in `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 5):

It should probably be

```
const GUEST = 1;     // 1
const USER = 2;      // 10
const MODERATOR = 8; // 1000
const ADMIN = 16;    // 10000
```

Comment: And when a user is admin i have to add 10000 to the permission field in the database?

Comment: @user1362916 Do you know what are binary numbers?

Answer (score 5):

The problem, [as Mikhail shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15120576/417562), is that `1000` is the number one-thousand. You need the number whose binary representation is `1000`, which is the number eight.

You can use `1`, `2`, `4`, `8`, `16`, etc., as Mikhail does.

However, if you want to visualise what's happening with the bitwise calculation, it's great if you can see where the bits are visually. PHP 5.4 introduced a binary integer syntax.

```
const GUEST     = 0b00001;  // 1
const USER      = 0b00010;  // 2
const MODERATOR = 0b01000;  // 8
const ADMIN     = 0b10000;  // 16
```