# Accessing object's properties in an array php

Tags: php, arrays, session, object

I have a session variable `$_SESSION["customer"]` which contains one object of the customer class, which has private properties such as firstname, lastname and so on. They can be accessed but public getters and setters. I don't know how to access them and use them in my code.

Here is a var_dump of `$_SESSION["customer"]`

```
object(Customer)#4 (13) { ["id":"Customer":private]=> string(4) "1019" ["fname":"Customer":private]=> string(4) "john" ["lname":"Customer":private]=> string(3) "doe" ["dob":"Customer":private]=> string(10) "1999-12-12" ["address1":"Customer":private]=> string(10) "humberwood" ["address2":"Customer":private]=> string(0) "" ["city":"Customer":private]=> string(7) "toronto" ["zip":"Customer":private]=> string(6) "m3a1c6" ["province":"Customer":private]=> string(2) "ON" ["gender":"Customer":private]=> string(1) "0" ["email":"Customer":private]=> string(21) "johndoe@humbermail.ca" ["username":"Customer":private]=> string(6) "humber" ["password":"Customer":private]=> string(6) "humber" }
```

I tried using `$username = $_SESSION["customer"]->Customer->getUsername();` but in vain

Comment: $username = $_SESSION['customer']->getUsername();

Comment: according to the exception you are getting, this answer may be a help http://stackoverflow.com/a/132197/905214

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, since using `$_SESSION['customer']` contains a `Customer` object.

```
$customer = $_SESSION['customer'];
$username = $customer->getUsername();
```

Comment: Throws an error `Fatal error: main(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition &quot;Customer&quot; of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded _before_ unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition`

Comment: That must mean that object's contents are private.

Comment: Try casting it @Shashank.

Comment: Could you please explain @kyle

Comment: It simply means that your Customer object is nothing but an object in its incomplete state while being stored in `$_SESSION`. refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132194/php-storing-objects-inside-the-session/132197#132197

Comment: I am trying to workaround it by storing only the customerid in the session and then re-firing the query on my DB, but still i am unable to get the value from the session, The var_dump is `string (4) 1019`. How do I can i retrieve only 1019?? @kyle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65252/discussion-between-kyle-emmanuel-and-shashank).