# PHP fill up multidimensional associative array - easiest way

Tags: php, arrays

I want to use `$_SESSION` to store items in cart. The items are defined by `id`, each item has 3 sizes and for each size there will be stored item's quantity. I would like to use multidimensional associative array like that

```
$_SESSION['cart']['id'.$_GET['id']]['size'.$_POST['size']]['quantity'] += $_POST['quantity'];
```

but I guess the problem which I am getting (`Notice: Undefined index`) is because the arrays are not defined first.

I would like to keep it simple, so what would be the easiest way?

Comment: Are you passing an `id` in your URL, and always sending a `size` and `quantity` in the POST data? Otherwise, there's your problem.

Comment: yes I do. there is also this in the code: `if(isset($_POST['size'])){...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you're just assuming the items are set in `$_SESSION`. You need to assume they aren't and start by adding them in.

You'd harness [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset).

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart']['id'.$_GET['id']])) {
    $_SESSION['cart']['id'.$_GET['id']] = array(
        'sizeONE' => array(
            'quantity' => 0
        ),
        'sizeTWO' => array(
            'quantity' => 0
        ),
        'sizeTHREE' => array(
            'quantity' => 0
        ),
    );
}
```

You'd obviously modify the above to probably only set the product id as you require then run through the same sort of `isset()` to add the selected sizes. I'm just showing you how to create the initial structure array.

Comment: I am not assuming they are set. They are not. I just wanted to know the easiest way to do that. Something like the code I wrote above. Maybe something like objects instead of arrays. By the way, how would your definition look like if even `id` is not set? Wouldn't it be too complex?

Comment: @koubin Too easy! Well, you'd essentially not store the product (id) in the session if it wasn't set, as you need that to identify the product?

Comment: I don't get the last comment, but I guess, something like that before code would do the trick: `if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){$_SESSION['cart'] = array();}` Am I right?

Comment: Perfectly right @koubin . What i meant with the last comment is that you wouldn't add a product to the cart session if the user didn't want to add it to there.

Comment: ok. thanks. I hoped for some simple and esthetic solution, but there is probably nothing like I have had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue the best manner to store this data isn't in a multidimensional array, but rather in an Object (and not in $_SESSION, but that's a whole different topic).

If you want to approach this with an object, I'd use a variation of the following:

```
$myItem = new stdClass;
$myItem->id = $_GET['id'];
$myItem->sizeOne = new stdClass;
$myItem->sizeOne->name = "sizeOne";
$myItem->sizeOne->quantity = 1;
// repeat for sizeTwo and sizeThree

$_SESSION['cart'][$myItem->id] = $myItem;
```

**Benefits:**

More of an [OOP approach](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) to your program.

**Drawbacks:**

Storing an Object in the $_SESSION may cause [scalability issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132194/php-storing-objects-inside-the-session).